# when we use @controller and MultiActionController together

Tags: spring

when we use @controller annotation  and extend our class with MultiActionController class together?
what is the situation when we need to do both things together?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do refine it to particular issue you face or is it that you look forward to any particular use case of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It seems MultiActionController (from spring 2.0 onwards) was introduced earlier in the evolution of spring MVC framework. @Controller was added from spring 2.5 Onwards. There seems to be NO use case for using both of these together.